# Blue spinning on every windows explorer navigation

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Recently I have been getting the blue spinner every time I navigate to a new folder in windows explorer. I am using Windows 10 Pro. I have a super fast computer and nothing else about it is running slow, so this is strange. It seemed to just randomly started happening a couple weeks ago. It only last for a second or 2 and then goes away, and only happens when navigating to a new directory. Any ideas? This doesnt actually slow anything down either or prevent me from doing anything, it seems to be purely visual.

Comment: If your computer has built-in diagnostics, have you run them? Specifically, have you checked your hard disk health? Also, do you have any network drives mapped as drive letters?

Comment: Suspect anti-virus or a third party application that is involved in thumbnail creation of the files in each folder.